# Downloading file issue using bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron

I knew how to connect to SFTP server and poll the files from the file server directory.

```
$sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/2017-05-05-00.zip  ~/local_machine/2017-05-05/
```

The file server updates the files on `/File` directory hourly.

Example ,

The file server adds first zip file at `7:00 AM` of the day(Ex:2017-05-05) as `2017-05-05-00.zip`.

Second file at `'8:00 AM'` as `2017-05-05-01.zip`.

Like this , 24 files will be updated for a day.

The last file of the day will be `2017-05-05-23.zip`.

Now , I also knew how to download all the files of a day and I will do that  next day ( Example : The 2017-05-05 files , I will download on next day 2017-05-06 )

```
#download.sh
sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/2017-05-05-00.zip  ~/local_machine/2017-05-05/
sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/2017-05-05-01.zip  ~/local_machine/2017-05-05/
sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/2017-05-05-02.zip  ~/local_machine/2017-05-05/
.................................................................
sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/2017-05-05-23.zip  ~/local_machine/2017-05-05
```

Instead of doing this download all at once , I would like to download it hourly. Like ,

```
2017-05-05-00.zip   7:00
2017-05-05-01.zip   8:00
2017-05-05-02.zip   9:00
2017-05-05-03.zip   10:00
2017-05-05-04.zip   11:00
2017-05-05-05.zip   12:00
2017-05-05-06.zip   13:00
2017-05-05-07.zip   14:00
2017-05-05-08.zip   15:00
2017-05-05-09.zip   16:00
2017-05-05-10.zip   17:00
2017-05-05-11.zip   18:00
2017-05-05-12.zip   19:00
2017-05-05-13.zip   20:00
2017-05-05-14.zip   21:00
2017-05-05-15.zip   22:00
2017-05-05-16.zip   23:00
2017-05-05-17.zip   0:00
2017-05-05-18.zip   1:00
2017-05-05-19.zip   2:00
2017-05-05-20.zip   3:00
2017-05-05-21.zip   4:00
2017-05-05-22.zip   5:00
2017-05-05-23.zip   6:00
```

I know a question might come up ?

How does the file names remain unchanged even after next day.

Even on the next day ( 2017-05-06)  , The file name remain unchanged until it finishes up with the last file of the previous day ( 2017-05-05-23.zip ).

How to schedule the download automatically to download the file for it's specified hour than downloading all the files at once .

Pretty much confused on how to use the logic here. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Cron with a date formatter?

Comment: I suggest to use rsync if you have access to the server with ssh.